# Picard's Theorem and Second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that if $u$ is a solution of the initial value problem $u^{\prime\prime} = -x^2u$, $u(0) = 1$, $u^{\prime}(0) = 0$, then it is a solution of the integral equation

$$u(x) = 1 - \int_0^x (x-s)(s^2)u(s) ds.$$

Consider the sequence $u_n(x)$ to be the iterated solutions to this integral equation. Assuming this sequence converges uniformly so that a solution exists, show that the solution is unique.

I literally have no idea how to do this problem - for the first bit I don't know if I need to integrate through the ODE. For the second bit, I think Picard's Theorem needs to be used but I don't know how.

Comment: I haven't done Gronwall's inequality yet - I have to do it with Picard's Theorem I think

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking uniqueness of solutions you can use Gronwall's inequality. For the existence case you can form a sequence $u_n(x)$ defined by $$u_{n+1}(x) = 1 - \int_0^x (x-s)(s^2)u_n(s) ds$$
and then you proceed to show that $u_n$ converges uniformly a function $u$ which is the solution of the problem.

Comment: what about doing this without Gronwall's inequality

Comment: As I know in order to apply that theorem you should convert the equation to a first-order system of equations by setting $y_1=u$ and $y_2=u'$. After converting to a system of ODEs you have $y'=f(x, y)$, $y(0)=(1, 0)$, where $y=(y_1, y_2)$ and $f(x, y)= (y_2, -x^2y_1)$. It is enough to verify that $f$ is (locally) Lipschitz.

Comment: thanks - I get that but how would I show f is locally Lipschitz

Comment: First choose a rectangle which contains IC and then show that $|f(x, y)-f(x, z)|\leq L|x-z|$ for some constant $L>0$, for $(x, y)$ and $(x, z)$ in your rectangle, where $|\cdot|$ represent an Euclidean norm in $\mathbf R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first bit, you want to use the same method used to derive Picard's iterative approximation method, but twice. And then you want and then use this trick to turn your double integral into a single integral: http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_order_integration_examples